# Change created_at & updated_at values on API response

Tags: laravel, api

Currently Getting This :-

```
 "created_at": "2022-03-26T09:08:44.000000Z",
 "updated_at": "2022-03-26T09:08:44.000000Z",
```

But Need This :-

```
"created_at": "2022-03-26 09:08:44",
"updated_at": "2022-03-26 09:08:44",
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: What have you tried so far ? did you use mutator ? have tried the date casting example in laravel documentation ? https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting

Comment: Yes Sir, The Below Answer Helped Me

Comment: If the answer worked for you, set it as "the answer" to close your question.

Answer (score 2):

The perfect solution for your question is already present in the [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting)

```
/**
 * Prepare a date for array / JSON serialization.
 *
 * @param  \DateTimeInterface  $date
 * @return string
 */
protected function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date)
{
    return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```